# Why is the period of Mersenne Twister prng $2^{19937}-1$ and not $2^{19968}$?

Tags: pseudo-random-generators, random-number-generator

For the Mersenne Twister prng, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Pseudocode), I feel the period exponent should be the size of the MT array,
$32\cdot 624 = 19968$.

How come the exponent is 19937 instead?

Comment: As this question is a about a _non-cryptographic_ PRNG, I'm migrating it over to [cs.se].

Comment: This is not at all an answer, but fwiw, if the period was $2^{19968}$, the authors wouldn't have called it a *Mersenne* Twister, since it's $2^{19937}-1$ that is a [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the one-line explanation.

The number of effective bits in MT19937 is 624*32-31=19937. They cannot be all 0. So the period of MT19937 is $2^{19937}-1$.

---

All notations if not introduced below come from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mersenne_Twister&oldid=896072298#Pseudocode). The parameters for MT19937, (w, n, m, r) = (32, 624, 397, 31) will be used from time to time.

#### Explanation from the recurrence

> The series $x$ is defined as a series of w-bit quantities with the recurrence relation:
>   $$x_{k+n}:=x_{k+m}\oplus \left(({x_{k}}^{u} \mid\mid {x_{k+1}}^{l})A\right)\qquad \qquad k=0,1,\ldots$$

Note the lower part of the lowest term $x_k$, ${x_k}^l$ is not used in the recurrence relation. Hence the number of effective bits used by the recurrence is $(k+n-k)w-r=nw-r$. Since 0 is excluded, the theoretical limit of period of Mersernne Twister is $2^{nw-r}-1=2^{19937}-1$.

#### Detailed explanation.

The above explanation is not rigorous enough because of a lack of proper reference. To convince myself, I followed [the established pseudocode implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mersenne_Twister&oldid=896072298#Pseudocode).

```
// Generate the next n values from the series x_i 
function twist() {
  for i from 0 to (n-1) {
    int x := (MT[i] and upper_mask)
              + (MT[(i+1) mod n] and lower_mask)
    int xA := x >> 1
    if (x mod 2) != 0 { // lowest bit of x is 1
         xA := xA xor a
    }
    MT[i] := MT[(i + m) mod n] xor xA
  }
  index := 0
}
```

The code above shows that the internal state of a Mersenne Twister is kept in MT[0], MT[1], ..., MT[n-1], which is an array of n values of w bits each. It seems that the period of a Mersenne Twister should be $2^{nw}=2^{19968}$.

Let us check the situation closely.

Every call to `twist()` will update the internal state. After each call to `twist()`, `function extract_number()` will be called $n$ times, each time extracting from `MT[index]` one word of w bits to output where `index` is one of 0, 1, ..., n-1.

How does `twist()` update the internal state?

- the upper w-r bits of MT[0], the lower r bits of MT[1], and all bits of MT[317] are used to update MT[0].
- the upper w-r bits of MT[1], the lower r bits of MT[2], and all bits of MT[318] are used to update MT[1].
- the upper w-r bits of MT[2], the lower r bits of MT[3], and all bits of MT[319] are used to update MT[2].
- ...
- the upper w-r bits of MT[306], the lower r bits of MT[307], and all bits of MT[623] are used to update MT[306].
- the upper w-r bits of MT[307], the lower r bits of MT[308], and all bits of the updated MT[0] are used to update MT[307].
- the upper w-r bits of MT[308], the lower r bits of MT[309], and all bits of the updated MT[1] are used to update MT[308].
- ...
- the upper w-r bits of MT[622], the lower r bits of MT[623], and all bits of the updated MT[315] are used to update MT[622].
- the upper w-r bits of MT[623], the lower r bits of updated MT[0], and all bits of the updated MT[316] are used to update MT[623].

Note that **all bits in the array MT at the start of `twist()` are used except the lower r bits of MT[0]**. So an effective internal state of MT is r bits less than all bits in array MT.  Since an effective internal state can never be all 0, the number of effective internal states is at most $2^{nw-r}-1=2^{19937}-1$, which is the theoretical limit of the period for a linear-feedback shift register like Mersenne Twister.

It is another level of interesting mathematical reasoning how MT19937 attains that theoretical limit of its period.

#### Another explanation by pseudocode

The following pseudocode is another implementation of Mersenne Twister.

Note the code `MT[0] := MT[0] and upper_mask` and `MT[0] := MT[1] and upper_mask`, which limits the number of effective bits in MT[0] to w-r. There are (n-1)w bits in MT[1], MT[2], ..., MT[n-1]. In total, there are (w-r)+(n-1)w = nw-r bits in the (effective) internal state of a Mersenne Twister.

```
// Adapted from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mersenne_Twister&oldid=896072298#Pseudocode by Apass.Jack

// Create a length n array to store the state of the generator
int[0..n-1] MT
int index := n+1
const int lower_mask = (1 << r) - 1 // That is, the binary number of r 1's
const int upper_mask = lowest w bits of (not lower_mask)

// Initialize the generator from a seed, which must be done once before repeated calls to next(). 
function seed_mt(int seed) {
    index := n
    MT[0] := seed
    for i from 1 to (n - 1) { // loop over each element
        MT[i] := lowest w bits of (f * (MT[i-1] xor (MT[i-1] >> (w-2))) + i)
    }
    MT[0] := MT[0] and upper_mask
}

function temper(int y) {
    y := y xor ((y >> u) and d)
    y := y xor ((y << s) and b)
    y := y xor ((y << t) and c)
    y := y xor (y >> l)

    return lowest w bits of (y)
}

function twist() {
    int x := MT[0]
              + (MT[1] and lower_mask)
    int xA := x >> 1
    if (x mod 2) != 0 { // lowest bit of x is 1
        xA := xA xor a
    }
    x := MT[m] xor xA

    MT[0] := MT[1] and upper_mask
    for i from 1 to (n-2) {
      MT[i] := MT[i+1]
    }
    MT[n-1] := x
}

// Generate the next value from the series MT[]  
function next() {
    twist()
    return temper(MT[n-1])
}
```